# Aspx page not completely filling iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have an iframe that has a an aspx page being loaded into it and I can't figure out the page that is being loaded won't fill in the iFrame.
The page being loaded has a div container, inside the grid is a toolbar and a grid, here is the code for the container

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid green;">
```

> ..Toolbar and Grid is in here

```
</div>
```

This is what it looks like when I run it, don't pay any attention at the border colors, those are there for me to make sure that the iFrame is filling the div. The grid and toolbar is bordered with green for a reference.
[image: What it looks like when it is ran]

I remember a long time ago that I was able to pull this of before, that was a very long time ago and I don't remember how I did it. So the question is how do I get the page to fill up the iframe?

Thanks

Comment: The default styling of the `body` element, across browsers, has some padding: this will apply inside an ifame as well.

Comment: @Richard, Gotcha. Can I remove the padding in the page that is being loaded? If so, I assume that I would put padding:0px in the body or css file for the page and that would allow me to fill in the complete iFrame?

Comment: Correct, it is just a matter of styling `body.`... and I'll make this an answer.

Comment: @Richard, perfect thanks. I'll accept as answer.

Comment: @Richard, I have to wait 6 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default styling of the body element, across browsers, has some padding: this will apply inside an ifame as well.

Thus you need to add some styling:

```
body, html {
  padding 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

to the CSS of the page inside the `iframe`.